# растянуть два textview на ширину экрана

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Есть три пары кнопок. Каждую пару хочу растянуть на всю ширину контейнера. Кнопки в виде TextView. Можно это как то сделать?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder"
    android:id="@+id/request_in_work"
    tools:context=".FragmentActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rectangleNumber"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTimeView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rectangleNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rectangleNumber" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/dateTimeView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateTimeView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cvalView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/address"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/address" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cvalView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvalView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/taskView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/taskView" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/endBtn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:onClick="onEndBtnClick"
        android:text="Завершить"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/description"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/declineBtn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="callBtn"
        android:text="Отказ"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/callBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/endBtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/callBtn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:onClick="callBtn"
        android:text="Прозвон"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/endBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/endBtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/delayBtn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="delayShow"
        android:text="Задержка"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/callBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/callBtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/changeTimeBtn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:text="Перенос"
        android:onClick="toAnotherDate"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/description"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/callBtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/callingBtn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="callBtn"
        android:text="Звонок"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/callBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/changeTimeBtn" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавил `android:layout_width="0dp"` ко всем кнопкам и конец каждой первой к началу второй         `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/declineBtn"`
и соответственно начало каждой второй к концу первой `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/endBtn"`
и конец второй кнопки привязать к контейнеру         `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`